# Elasticsearch - how to filter over a list of nested objects

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a list of object and I need to get only the objects based on the value of his children, for example, given the example below how can I retrieve only the people that have some children with age greater than a given age parameter?

```
hits:[
person:{
   value1: "something",
   value2: "something",
   children: [
      {age:18},
      {age:20}
   ]
}]
```

I have tried something with query context but without success:

```
{
  "min_score": 0.1,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": """
              if (params["_source"]["children"][0]['age'] === params.age) {
                return 1;
              }else{
                return 0;
              """,
              "params": {
                "age": "20"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `nested` data type mapping and a nested query to go along with it.

Rudimentary mapping:

```
PUT persons
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "person": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "children": {
            "type": "nested"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

An inserted person:

```
POST persons/_doc
{
  "person": {
    "value1": "something",
    "value2": "something",
    "children": [
      {
        "age": 18
      },
      {
        "age": 20
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Searching for children of the exact age of 20:

```
GET persons/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "person.children",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "person.children.age": {
            "value": 20
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You could also use a [range query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html) with `gte` == `lte` == 20.